# Android app on Lollipop behaves differently from older versions

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have developed and published an app for riddles. I have a problem with Lollipop devices, I built and ran the app on KitKat and Jelly Bean and it works. But when it comes to Lollipop the background drawable of the main activity is not set but white. Furthermore in the settings activity the customizedthumbs have no more the color I have set but are nearly invisible and the app crashes when starting a slide activity and a fragment backcard action.

All the points I list work great on pre-Lollipop versions:

1) Background main activity:

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(arrayBackground[backgroundChoice]);
```

2) Thumbs switch are set based on sharedPreferences:

```
 switchRisolti.setThumbResource(R.color.blue);
```

3) Start slide activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Impostazioni.this, ScreenSlideActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);`
```

4) fragment flipcard:

```
//LOAD FRAGMENT
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
CardFrontFragment fragment = new CardFrontFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `res` holder, probably you have a `values-v21` folder in it which specifies a `style.xml` which is used from Lollipop and newer versions.

Comment: thanks for fast reply, the folder was not present in the signed apk, i added it now as i read from another stackoverflow answer, but i set the content same as values/style.xml: here is style content: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
 and here style(v-21): <resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    </style>
</resources> sorry for bad formatting but as soon as i press enter or tab it sends the comment